# Iterate over the types in a Tuple DataType

Tags: julia

Is there a way to iterate over the types contained in a `Tuple{...}` DataType? For instance, if I have the type `Tuple{String, Int}`, I'd like to be able to use something like `values(Tuple{String, Int})` to return an iterator of `String` and `Int`, like this:

```
julia> collect(values(Tuple{String, Int}))
2-element Array{DataType,1}:
 String
 Int64
```

But of course that doesn't actually work:

```
julia> values(Tuple{String, Int})
Tuple{String,Int64}

julia> collect(values(Tuple{String, Int}))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Type{Tuple{String,Int64}})
Closest candidates are:
  length(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:596
  length(::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:852
  length(::Core.MethodTable) at reflection.jl:938
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] _similar_for(::UnitRange{Int64}, ::Type{Any}, ::Type{T} where T, ::Base.HasLength) at ./array.jl:576
 [2] _collect(::UnitRange{Int64}, ::Type{T} where T, ::Base.HasEltype, ::Base.HasLength) at ./array.jl:609
 [3] collect(::Type{T} where T) at ./array.jl:603
 [4] top-level scope at REPL[30]:1
```

I would prefer a solution that does not involve digging into the internals of `DataType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tuple type is only a `DataType`. Everything operating on it will have to involve `DataTypes` -- you're looking for a function of type `DataType -> [DataType]`. One possible answer is `Tuple{String, Int}.parameters`.  At least in 1.3, `Core.Compiler` also contains

```
datatype_fieldtypes(x::DataType) = ccall(:jl_get_fieldtypes, Any, (Any,), x)
```

which only internal and undocumented, though.  Both result in a `Core.SimpleVector`.

But then I remembered that tuple parts can be treated both as indices and as fields.  So it turns out `fieldtypes` would probably be your favourite:

```
julia> fieldtypes(Tuple{Int, String})
(Int64, String)
```

The other methods, however, have the advantage that you can use them with *any* parametrized type.  This often comes in handy in generated functions.